# ReportViewer no muestra datos actualizados (c# winforms)

Tags: c#, windows-forms, reportviewer

tengo una aplicacion en c# que controla el stock de un comercio.
tiene una base de datos integrada (basada en servicio), un reportviewer muestra el listado de articulos.
El reporte y el dataset se creo en modo diseño.
todo funciona bien, pero parece que el dataset solo se carga en la primera visualizacion  ya que si cambio un registro y vuelvo a generar el reporte, los datos son los antiguos.
Si cierro la aplicacion y vuelvo a ejecutar y voy derecho a generar el reporte, ahí sí se ven los cambios.
el procedimiento almacenado de t-sql es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ListarTodos]

AS
SELECT ARTICULOS.COD_ARTICULO, ARTICULOS.DESCR_ARTICULO,
ARTICULOS.PRECIO_ARTICULO, ARTICULOS.STOCK_ARTICULO
from
ARTICULOS
order by  ARTICULOS.STOCK_ARTICULO desc, ARTICULOS.DESCR_ARTICULO asc
RETURN 0
```

El dataset, tambien contiene otro procedimiento para otro reporte que tiene el mismo defecto (no obtiene datos actualizados)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca muestro el formulario que contiene el reportview, el reporte lo generé en diseño

```
public partial class form_ListadoDeProductos : Form
{
    public form_ListadoDeProductos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void form_ListadoDeProductos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'BaseDeDatosDataSet.ListarTodos' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        this.ListarTodosTableAdapter.Fill(this.BaseDeDatosDataSet.ListarTodos);

        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
}
}
```

no he añadido nada mas de lo que genera visual al insertar el reporte e indicar fuente de datos (el rldc) que se creo igual en modo diseño, ya que inserté una tabla en el reporte y le indiqué el dataset.

Comment: Da mas de detalles, para entenderte mejor

Comment: ok, disculpas. la aplicacion controla el stock de un comercio,  debe mostrar mediante un reporte el listado de articulos, lo hace perfecto pero si modifico algun articulo en el mismo programa y vuelvo a generar el reporte, éste cambio no se ve reflejado. para que tome los cambios debo cerrar el programa y volverlo a abrir. es el visual 2019, use reportviewer, una base basada en servicio integrada, y el dataset en modo diseño cuando cree el reporte

Comment: Se refiere a que agregues código de la parte donde tienes el problema, esto con la finalidad de replicarlo o en su defecto checar si tienes algún error de lógica que no hayas detectado.

Comment: aah. ok, voy a rehacer la consulta y agregar mas detalles

Comment: Mira en la linea 43 del tu archivo de reporte ahi esta el error. Ahora hablando en serio como te pueden ayudar si no se ve nada de tu codigo.

Comment: ya agregué mas detalles, igualmente mucho codigo no hay en esa funcion ya que lo generé todo en modo diseño, al reporte y los dataset

Answer (score 0):

al final el problema estaba en que al crear el dataset en modo diseño crea una nueva cadena de conexion en app.config y esta apunta a la copia que hace el visual cuando compila en la carpeta bin.
lo resolvi modificando esa cadena a donde esta la base.